# Droppable not working with cloned element

Tags: jquery, clone, draggable, droppable

I have a drag and drop system and it's all working fine. I have multiple divs that are droppable and multiple divs that are draggable.
Then i implemented a clone system to the droppable area, so my droppable divs can all be cloned, and that's working fine too.

The problem it's when i try to drag elements to the cloned draggable areas.
The draggable divs don't detect the cloned droppable areas as a droppable area, i only can drag the elements to the original dropp areas.

Do i need to update something to let the draggable divs to know that there's new elements that are droppable?

---EDIT---

To everyone with the same problem, you need to destroy the droppable before the clone.
So in your clone function, just put this

```
$(".drop").droppable( "destroy" );
```

and then clone, and after that you call the droppable function again.

Comment: My guess without knowing what plugin you are using would be that yes, you should update the plugin whenever you create new droppable areas. The plugin should have some 'update' or 'refresh' method that you can use to do that.

Comment: I'm using Jquery UI. I tried to refresh with JS but that doesn't work because when the pages is refreshed the cloned elements are gone (wich is normal because i'm not saving anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery UI in your set up? You should try to change the class name of your draggable divs once they've been moved. Try using:

```
$( "#draggable" ).addClass( "newClassName" );
```

Once you've done that set up your droppable to accept that item. Sounds like jQuery UI think's your item has already been dropped.

```
 $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      accept: ".newClassName",
```

Comment: Yes, i'm using Jquery UI. But, if i do that, i have to create the connection between the divs again because the class has changed.

Comment: unfortunately no, now it's not working in the original too.

Comment: I'm on a tablet right now, as soon as i put my hands on my computer i post the code.

Comment: Well, my system is pretty complex, i cannot implement on jsfiddle properly. But i made a simple example like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ang5v3es/4/

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are looking for you can reinitialise the newly created droppables by calling an update function on the drop event. I came to this using the example you provided. Try it out.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
             $(".duplicatedrop").click(
            function () {
            $(".drop").clone(true, true).appendTo(".drop");
            }
        );

    $(function() {
        $( ".drag" ).draggable({
            revert: true,
            cursor: 'move'
        });
    });


    updateDroppables();

    function updateDroppables(){
        $( ".drop" ).droppable({
            accept: ".drag",
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).find( "p" ).html( "Dropped!" );
                var clone = $(this).clone();
                clone.appendTo('body');
                updateDroppables();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: I don't quite understand where do i put that, in the normal function? after the "accept"?

Comment: For a start you should have shown what you've made so far instead of just asking a plain question. But as far as I can tell you should use that whenever you create a new element. When you first initialise the plugin only the elements that already exist will be affected so if you want to the new ones to have that behavior you have to enabled them when they are created.

Comment: I'm on the computer right now, i will try to show in a few minutes. But, btw, that didn't work

Comment: Well, my system is pretty complex, i cannot implement on jsfiddle properly. But i made a simple example like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ang5v3es/2/

Comment: i made some mistakes in that onde, https://jsfiddle.net/ang5v3es/5/    The thing is: that's not what is happening in my example, what is going in this example it's that he just apply in both

Comment: Check the example I posted the answer.

Comment: It doesn't work, but it's weird, because in the inspector i see the new divs, but the draggable items just don't detect them

Comment: Oh, i forgot, i'm not reaching the droppable area by class, because all of them have same class, so i'm reaching the area with .closest, i tried with the same class and it works like in the example, it replace in all areas.

Comment: Ok i tried something. I tried to call the drag and drop function only after de clone and that way it works, but because i only call it after the drop i cannot drag until i clone, wich it's not what i want. Is there a way to stop a function and call another?

Comment: Using the example you provided I managed to get my droppable area cloned everytime I dragged and dropped over it and the same for newly created droppables with the peice of code I showed you. If that doesn't work in your actual project maybe is something else that is causing troubles?

Comment: Maybe, i'm running many tests now to see if there's anything causing troubles.

Comment: So, now iv'e created a variable(dropOptions) that has the drop proprierties from the droppable function, and then after the clone, i make: "$( ".drop" ).children().droppable(dropOptions);"   It works! BIG BUT...only works on first clone! the clones after that no...

Comment: So, now, my question is: Is there a way to define all the childrens instead of only the first?

Comment: I already have a solution, if you're interested, see the initial post. Thank's for the help!

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. Cheers